# embed sendSMS() with html on a website

Tags: html, embed, twilio, sendmessage, branch.io

https://dev.branch.io/features/text-me-the-app/guide/

I try to embed the html snippet into a website in order to let users input their phone numbers and send them messages manually. This is a template that offered by Branch.IO(regardless to the branch key) but I could not get the message when I input my own phone number. Can you address the problem of this html code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](//meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Answer (score -1):

Alex from Branch.io here: if you're referring to this [example code](https://dev.branch.io/features/text-me-the-app/guide/#insert-sendsms-snippet-into-your-page), then it should be working correctly. I just checked it and was able to receive an SMS as expected.

If you're using an international phone number, make sure you're entering the full country code.

Comment: I used an US phone number and I embed this code via strikingly in my website. But, I receive no message after I entered and submitted the number. @Alex Bauer

Comment: Could you show us the example currently embedded in your website? That will help with debugging

Comment: I used the exact code in your example.code link which is the default template from branch.io. The only change that I made is "YOUR BRANCH KEY" because I have to enter my correct branch key. I received no message on both IPhone(T-Mobile) and Android(Verizon). I checked the twilio message log and it indicated that the message has been seen out. But, I just never got any message. Does it have anything to do with the "send me app" setting on Brand.IO? @Alex Bauer

Comment: Hi Kevin, again, could you show us the example as it is currently embedded in your website? Not much we can do without this I'm afraid. Feel free to send in an [integrations ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) if you don't want to post this in public